# How to use custom image when creating alicloud instance using Terraform

Tags: terraform, devops, alibaba-cloud

Im setting up a new instance using terraform for alicloud provider, how do I specify custom image when creating instance resource?

I've put custom "image_id" to resource image_id, but error shows up

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your Terraform code and the exact error you get when you apply it?

Comment: Do you still need answer for this question? Please provide us more details about your codes.

Comment: @Abel its done, i have to upgrade alicloud client

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following documentation links:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/alicloud/index.html

And following Alibaba Cloud OpenAPI Explorer:
https://api.aliyun.com/#/cli?tool=Terraform&module=ecs-instance&namespace=alibaba

Hope this helps!